# Basic C++ / Thresholding and Filtering an image

Tags: c++, image, filtering, rgb

Good day to everyone!

I started learning C++ by myself a couple of weeks ago. I am now hoping to take on a small project; using my Ubuntu machine id like to run a code that can threshold an RGB image and then filter it according to certain values that I'll input myself.

How should I proceed? What should i keep in my mind when trying? And how long do you reckon should it take? Keep in mind that i have 0 prior experience in coding.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! Stack Overflow is better suited for specific questions rather than general advices... nevertheless, I would suggest you to take a look at some OpenCV tutorials to start with

Comment: Thank you for your reply! so i directly found a tutorial for thresholding, which looks great! but no apparent one for image filtering. Is filtering not the actual term used? what im trying to do is use the thresholded image to then change its pixel values to change its colors.

Answer (score 2):

For first experiments, I suggest you consider only grayscale images or just the intensity channel of an RGB image.
Anyway, if you have some image data:

1. Read the image (`libjpeg` etc)
2. You should have the data in a big array. If the image is really, really big, you should do the following thing chunk-based.
3. Apply the threshold: You enter a threshold, if the image value is below the threshold, you keep it and set all other values to zero. Maybe the other way around, as you please.

For point 1, try starting with [`pgm`](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgma/pgma.html) images as they are really easy to read (cf. Wikipedia).
For most managable `pgm` images, you might not need chunk realization, just load the entire thing into one big array of fitting type.

Edit: Some code, consider the concrete assembly to runnable C++ code as an exercise ;)

```
std::ifstream file("your-filename.pgm", std::ifstream::binary);
// Read header information:
// Check out wikipedia article and the C++ documentation for ifstream.
char magic[2]; // magic number, P2 or P5
file.read(magic, 2);
if (magic[0] != 'P' || magic[1] < '1' || magic[1] > '5') {
  throw std::exception("Invalid magic number");
}
int width, height, maxValue;
file >> width >> height >> maxValue;
if (maxValue <= 0 || maxValue >= (1 << 16)) {
  throw std::exception("Max value must be resonable");
}
file.ignore(1);

std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> data(new unsigned char[width * height * sizeof(unsigned char)]);
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.get()), width * height * sizeof(unsigned char));
// Now, the smart pointer 'data' contains your image grayscale data.
```

Be cautious: Some pgm files use `unsigned short` instead of `unsigned char`, but this information is inside the file header (you can identify that by the `maxValue` field).
After you loaded the data like above, you can just iterate over that array, do your processing (thresholding) and write the processed file to disk again.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm sorry if this will pass off as very inexperienced, but i cant seem to find the code that would let me load an image into an array/vector.

Comment: That's no problem, we are here for help ;)
I'll adapted my answer, hope this helps you.